# How to validate user login using Procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Currently i am working in validate user login, so using procedure to compare username and password to signupform table, then find a recordset value is >0 (success) or <0 (failed), but i am not very well in procedure concept, i tried my level best but i can't fix this, please help me.
Thanks in Advance

Here i have tried this:

```
Create table signupform (username varchar(10), password varchar(10)); 
Insert into signupform values ('sampath','s96000');
Insert into signupform values ('yuvaraj','y96297');
select * from signupform;

// CREATE PROCEDURE for compare username and password
create procedure testing (@username varchar(10), @password varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
select * from signupform where username = @username and password = @password
End;
```

Comment: Why don't you create a function and return the number of rows (probably 0 or 1). Check the docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to you create function:

```
create function testing(@username varchar(10), @password varchar(10))
RETURNS bit
BEGIN
   if EXISTS(select * from signupform where username = @username and password = @password)
   then
      return 1;
   else
      return 0; 
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: wait i check it. check answer again.

Comment: wow!I just copied this section of code and changed the table name for me. It threw an error. right syntax to use near '@username. Can anyone help? Mysql version 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if some login/pwd exist in your user table

```
if EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM signupform WHERE username = @username AND password = @password)
begin

set @res = 1;
end

    select @res as valid
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make sure you return a value regardless, this way you don't need to worry about counting rows

```
IF EXISTS(  
   SELECT *  
   FROM signupform  
   WHERE username = @username AND password = @password)  
BEGIN  
   SELECT 'Y'  
END  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
   SELECT 'N'  
END
```

Alternatively do a count, probably less efficient though

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM signupform  
WHERE username = @username AND password = @password
```

Answer (score -1):

Try these `SELECT` statements:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(@TypeName, 3)) into @TypeCode;
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(BranchName, 3)) into @Branch from tbl_erp_branches where BranchId=BranchIds;
-- SELECT UPPER(LEFT(AccountHeadName, 3)) into @Head from fin_erp_account_head where AccountHeadId=AccountHeadIds;
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(AccountHeadName, 3)) into @Head from fin_erp_account_head where AccountHeadId=AccountHeadIds;
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(CurrencyCode, 3)) into @Currency from tbl_erp_currency where CurrencyId=CurrencyIds;
```