# Function doesn't return 0/1 according to whether data exists

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a function to return 1 if `select 1 from users where NameUser = 'jim' and Password = 'Password'` returns a value (which it does in my DB), else `0`.

Create the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (`NameUser` varchar(40), `Password` varchar(20));
insert into `users` values('jim','Password');
```

Here is the code:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS validLogin;

DELIMITER $$
create function validLogin(uname varchar(40), upass varchar(20))
RETURNS binary
BEGIN
   if EXISTS(select 1 from users where NameUser = @uname and Password = @upass)
   then
      return 1;
   else
      return 0; 
   end if;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

select validLogin('jim','Password') as valid;
```

However, the above always returns `0`. I have confirmed that my tables are `varchar(40)` and `varchar(20)`.

How do I fix this?

I got the idea from this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11264385

EDIT: changed return values to binary
EDIT: added create and insert, fixed wrong column reference

Comment: OT: It is weird to say the function returns an `int` but then write a string in your `return` statements.

Comment: I have tried it returning binary and true/false ... but always returns 0 ... I changed it to make more sense ... thanks

Comment: `NameFirst` is the password column?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I can't believe I missed that. VTC as a simple typographic error, that is!

Comment: I was experimenting with the script and obviously forgot to return it too Password table ... woops

Comment: OK, by modifying the script to declare $ret and set $ret and then return $ret, I can get an output of BLOB in workbench when I run this: select validLogin('jim','Password') as valid; ... I'm not sure how I get a BLOB output from a binary .... ahhhh

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up on using a function and went to a stored procedure instead ...

the following returns the ndx of the user if Uname && Pwd match the DB.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `User_Validate`(
    IN `UName` varchar(40) ,
    IN `Pwd` varchar(88)
)
BEGIN
   select
     ndx
   from
     users
   where
     users.NameUser = UName
      and users.AESPwd = AES_ENCRYPT(Pwd, UNHEX(SHA2(Pwd,512)))
      and users.IsActive = 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you were having here concerns the difference between the variables you use as input parameters (uname and upass) and the user-defined variables (@uname and @upass) you then use in the SELECT statement. These are completely separate variables. Your SELECT, tests for equivalence with two uninitialized variables with value NULL rather than the parameters passed into the function - so no match.

You'll see the difference with this short example procedure

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS param_user_var //
CREATE PROCEDURE param_user_var(IN uname VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
  SELECT uname AS 'input param', @uname AS 'user defined variable' ;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL param_user_var('me');
+-------------+-----------------------+
| input param | user defined variable |
+-------------+-----------------------+
| me          | NULL                  |
+-------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you look back at the example you copied you'll notice that the poster has used user-defined variables throughout, so the input parameters are @username and @password and the same variables are used in the SELECT.